# Can't deploy YouTrack on Tomcat 7 (org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException)

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, servlets, youtrack

I'm trying to install YouTrack. I installed Tomcat 7 and that works fine (I'm able to load localhost:8080). Now I'm trying to deploy YouTrack. I followed the instructions on their website:

> 1. Deploy youtrack-xx.war in Tomcat servlet container:
>
>    1. If you run Tomcat (e.g. as a Windows service), stop Tomcat instance before deploying YouTrack.
>    2. Save `youtrack-xx.war` in the `$TOMCAT_HOME$/webapps` directory. Rename `youtrack-xx.war` file as required before deploying. In the
>         further examples we assume that the YouTrack servlet name is set to
>         `youtrack.war`.
>    3. Start Apache Tomcat and check whether YouTrack is set up correctly and is available (in a web browser navigate to
>         `http://yourserver:<Tomcat port>/youtrack`).

At step 3. I can't access YouTrack. I get a 404. If I go to the management site of Tomcat, it says that the Running state of YouTrack is false. If I click Start, it will display this error message:

```
FAIL - Application at context path /youtrack could not be started
FAIL - Encountered exception org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: 
       Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/youtrack]]
```

I looked at `logs/catalina.out` and this is the full error:

```
Information: Deploying web application directory /usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.50/webapps/youtrack
Feb 02, 2014 3:19:26 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase addChildInternal
Schwerwiegend: ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/youtrack]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:634)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1230)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1876)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/xml/DOMConfigurator
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2397)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1806)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.Introspection.getDeclaredFields(Introspection.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadFieldsAnnotation(WebAnnotationSet.java:263)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationServletAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:67)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationAnnotationsConfig(ContextConfig.java:407)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:883)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:378)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5343)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1702)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
    ... 24 more

Feb 02, 2014 3:19:26 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
Schwerwiegend: Error deploying web application directory /usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.50/webapps/youtrack
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/youtrack]]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:904)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:634)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1230)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1876)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

It looks like some classes are missing, but the one that is referenced in the error does actually exist:

`$TOMCAT$/webapps/youtrack/org/apache/log4j/xml`:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to give youtrack more memory? It solved similar issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a brand new Tomcat installation, or are there some modifications made in terms of %TOMCAT%\lib folder content? Could this be the case that you have the issue described under Update in this comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8832023/469159?